# How to chain multiple radial-gradients together and place them in different areas

Tags: css

I am trying to recreate this gradient background in CSS: 
[image: Gradient Background]

What I have attempted is the following:

```css
background: radial-gradient(circle at 90% 100%, var(--yellow) 0%, rgb(var(--gradient-blend)) 30%),
              radial-gradient(circle at 100% 90%, var(--blue), rgb(var(--gradient-blend)));
```

Though, this only displayed the following:[image]

What do I need to change to make the blue gradient appear?

Comment: The variables are the colors you see in the images (and they are all valid)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply multiple css radial gradients to a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677429/how-to-apply-multiple-css-radial-gradients-to-a-single-element)

Comment: also [How to create a website background with double radial gradients blended together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632645/how-to-create-a-website-background-with-double-radial-gradients-blended-together)

Comment: The key in both anwers is applying `transparent` to each gradient so that the others can show through. Also a very nice generator, and excellent css resource in general [joshwcomeau: Gradient Generator](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/gradient-generator/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but they don't apply the transition gradient (the dark blue). I guess I want to apply a background to the background?

Comment: They do apply to it, but your circles are overlapping `circle at 100% 90%` should be `circle at 0% 10%` or some such to draw the blue in the top left corner, and you need to add a `transparent` section to the end of the yellow gradient in order for the blue to show through. see [Reproduce a complex gradient in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564098/reproduce-a-complex-gradient-in-css) for another example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that `background` is just shorthand.  That means that you can stack `background-images` on top of a `background-color`.

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: 
  radial-gradient(circle at top left, blue 0%, transparent 50%),
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, yellow 0%, transparent 50%);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```